# HTML Form Case Sensitive

Tags: php, sql, rows, case-sensitive

This might be a rather weird question, but when I log in to my webpage, it works, even if I write it all in CAPITALS. Anyway, I've made a "kill" function on the page (Role playing game where you can kill others). And I've tried to make a simple function to make you unable to kill yourself. Here is the code:

```
        if ("$killuser"=="$user") {
        echo "You can't kill yourself!";
        }
```

$user = The current user logged in, trying to use the function

$killuser = The input in the HTML form (the user you are trying to kill)

The problem is, if my username is "User", and I attempt to kill "User", it says I can't kill myself, but if I write it in capitals, or not EXACTLY as it's stored in the database, it won't, and I'll be able to kill myself. By the way, the username table in the database is a VARCHAR and collation is utf8_general_ci.

Comment: i recommend to use the `id` from users...

Comment: It's questions like these where "the gloves come off", ouch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert both variables to lower-case and then compare it:

```
if ( strtolower($killuser) == strtolower($user)) {
    echo "You can't kill yourself!";
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php):

```
if (strcasecmp($killuser, $user) == 0) {
    echo "You can't kill yourself!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strtolower($killuser) == strtolower($user)) {
    echo "You can't kill yourself!";
}
```

just make everything lowercase and you won't have an issue.

Comment: @AmalMurali He left out the space between `(` and `strtolower`

Comment: disregard mine. i must have been typing it when you were typing yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/strcasecmp)

```
if (strcasecmp($killuser, $user) == 0) {
    echo '$var1 is equal to $var2 in a case-insensitive string comparison';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this without quotes

```
if ($killuser == strtolower($user)) {
```

This will make it in lower caps

Comment: And how is this supposed to be different?

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui - you need to cast both to the same case.